# Returning a generic type without T at compile time

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a list of generics defined like so:

```cs
class Registrations
{
    private readonly List<MetaRegistration> _registrations = new List<MetaRegistration>();

    private abstract class MetaRegistration
    {
    }

    private class Registration<T> : MetaRegistration
    {
        public async Task<T> Resolve(string value)
        {
            return await ...
        }
    }
}
```

And I'd like to run a method on one of the `Registration<T>` instances.

I can easily do it like this if I know the type at compile time:

```cs
public async Task<T> Resolve<T>(string value)
{
    var registration = _registrations.Cast<Registration<T>>()
        .First(r => r.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0] == typeof(T));
    var model = await registration.Resolve(value);
    return model;
}
```

But how would I go about this without when I don't know T?

Right now, this is how I've come around the problem using reflection, where I know the Type, but only during runtime:

```cs
public async Task<object?> Resolve(Type type, string value)
{
    foreach (var metaRegistration in _registrations)
    {
        Type t = metaRegistration.GetType();
        if (!t.IsGenericType || t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Registration<>) ||
            t.GenericTypeArguments[0] != type) continue;
        var methodInfo = metaRegistration.GetType().GetMethod("Resolve");
        var task = (Task) methodInfo?.Invoke(metaRegistration, new object?[] {value})!;
        await task;
        
        return task.GetType().GetProperty("Result")?.GetValue(task);
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, I would prefer to avoid reflection together, and this feels like I'm doing something incorrectly.

Is there any other way to go about this?

Comment: You're not going to avoid reflection or moral equivalents. When you consume generics, you're expected to know the types at your compile time (either with explicit types or, if your own code is generic, using your type parameters)

Comment: This is also often an indication that generics was in fact the wrong tool to use here and perhaps what you needed instead was e.g. an interface

Comment: You can use `switch/case` with [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#pattern-matching-with-the-switch-statement) and all types listed. There is no automatic conversion from `Type` to `T` like you want, somewhere you either decide at compile time which type to use or go with reflection.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'd love to use an interface, I'm working with EF Core entities and these are often replaced when the database is updated, removing interfaces/attributes that may already be placed.  :/

Comment: Indeed you don't need to *write* all that reflection by hand as you already happily using `dynamic`...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov good point ;) I've refactored that

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You've inspired me. I've looked into how I could extend EF Core and add an abstract class to each entity during scaffolding. This has simplified my process greatly. Thank you! :)